# How to show missing days in query which uses join on calendar table in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

How do I show the missing days in the query below which uses a join on a calendar table in SQL Server 2012?

The values for the missing day should be 0.

```
;WITH g AS
(
SELECT calendar.year, calendar.month, calendar.day, calendar.MonthName,
CAST(calendar.day AS NVARCHAR(2)) + '.' + CAST(calendar.month AS NVARCHAR(2)) + '.' + CAST(calendar.year AS NVARCHAR(16))AS DayMonthAndYear,
calendar.MonthName + ' ' + CAST(calendar.year AS NVARCHAR(16)) AS MonthNameAndYear,
COUNT(profileviews.ID) AS total_profileviews
FROM core_Calendar AS calendar
LEFT JOIN members_ProfileViews AS profileviews
ON CONVERT(DATE, calendar.date) = CONVERT(DATE, profileviews.CreatedAt)
WHERE calendar.date >= CONVERT(DATE, '03.02.2015')
AND calendar.date <= CONVERT(DATE, '03.02.2016')
AND profileviews.MemberID = 10
GROUP BY calendar.year, calendar.month, calendar.day, calendar.MonthName
)
SELECT g.year, g.month, g.day, g.MonthName, g.DayMonthAndYear, g.MonthNameAndYear, total_profileviews,
SUM(g.total_profileviews) OVER (ORDER BY g.year,g.month,g.day ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS rt_profileviews
FROM g
ORDER BY g.year, g.month, g.day;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `profileviews.MemberID = 10` to the `LEFT JOIN`, since it's essentially converting it to an `INNER JOIN`:

```
WITH g AS
(
    SELECT  C.[year], 
            C.[month], 
            C.[day], 
            C.[MonthName],
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),C.[date],104) AS DayMonthAndYear,
            C.[MonthName] + ' ' + CAST(C.[year] AS NVARCHAR(16)) AS MonthNameAndYear,
            COUNT(profileviews.ID) AS total_profileviews
    FROM core_Calendar AS C
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT *
                FROM members_ProfileViews
                WHERE MemberID = 10) AS P
        ON CONVERT(DATE, C.[date]) = CONVERT(DATE, P.CreatedAt)
    WHERE C.[date] >= CONVERT(DATE, '03.02.2015',104)
    AND C.[date] <= CONVERT(DATE, '03.02.2016',104)
    GROUP BY C.[year], C.[month], C.[day], C.[MonthName]
)
SELECT  g.[year], 
        g.[month], 
        g.[day], 
        g.[MonthName], 
        g.DayMonthAndYear, 
        g.MonthNameAndYear, 
        total_profileviews,
        SUM(g.total_profileviews) OVER (ORDER BY g.[year],g.[month],g.[day] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS rt_profileviews
FROM g
ORDER BY g.[year], g.[month], g.[day];
```